# Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' Diff Detector Kingsway Soft

Tags: ssis, kingswaysoft

> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.
>   The ProcessInput method on component "Diff Detector" (501) failed with error code 0xC02090F9 while processing input "Old Data Input" (510). 
>   The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

This kind of error was thrown while comparing entities from CRM sources in Diff Detector Component of Kingsway Soft Productivity Pack

Comment: Do you actually have enough memory on this machine to run this operation? Maybe try on a machine with more RAM?

Comment: There should be another error message which is being thrown by our component, could you please provide the other error messages?

You can email us directly with all the error messages for best response. We also have a hot fix build which may help, we can provide you with the build through email.

Answer (score 0):

If setting the default buffer size and default max rows to maximum allowed values doesn't work, you will most likely have to resort to sql/stored proc to perform your task. In my experience, doing so will actually be more efficient (80-90% faster) and is most of the times easy to implement once you've pulled both datasets in staging tables.

Comment: Information: The buffer manager failed a memory allocation call for 2147483647 bytes, but was unable to swap out any buffers to relieve memory pressure. 3 buffers were considered and 3 were locked. 
Either not enough memory is available to the pipeline because not enough are installed, other processes were using it, or too many buffers are locked.